# Why are primes important in cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, primes

One thing that always strikes me as a non-cryptographer: Why is it so important to use prime numbers? What makes them so special in cryptography?

Does anyone have a *simple* short explanation? (I am aware that there are many primers and that Applied Cryptography is the Bible, but as said: I am not looking to implement my own cryptographic algorithm, and the stuff that I found just made my brain explode - no ten pages of math formulas please).

Comment: A couple observations:
1. People below mention that "prime factorization of large numbers takes a long time". Actually, the same is true for any factorization. What's important is that any integer != 0 has a unique factorization as product of primes (including 1, which has decomposition of length 0).

Comment: 2. Please check my explanation why primes are important for hash-functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus/20206663#20206663
It is related to the property of polynomials with coefficients belonging to a field (which is probably not a short explanation).

Comment: Overly simple short explanation → Solve: `a * b = 91`.  Now, solve: `13 * 7 = x`.  The second equation is much quicker to solve (for a human or a computer).

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Most basic and general explanation: cryptography is all about [number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory), and all integer numbers (except 0 and 1) are made up of primes, so you deal with primes a lot in number theory.

More specifically, some important cryptographic algorithms such as [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) critically depend on the fact that [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) of large numbers takes a long time. Basically you have a "public key" consisting of a product of two large primes used to encrypt a message, and a "secret key" consisting of those two primes used to decrypt the message. You can make the public key public, and everyone can use it to encrypt messages to you, but only you know the prime factors and can decrypt the messages. Everyone else would have to factor the number, which takes too long to be practical, given the current state of the art of number theory.

Comment: As we enter the era of quantum computing it seems appropriate to note that the factorization of primes using a quantum computer can be achieved in polynomial time usiong Shor's Algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm

It's likely that computers already exist which can decrypt public key encryption like RSA

Comment: @stujo: you're massively overestimating the state of quantum computing. It is in fact certain that no such computer exists. The largest number that has been factored using Shor's Algorithm and bleeding-edge research efforts in quantum hardware is 21. That's not 21 bits, but the number 21, prime factors 3 and 7.

Comment: I'm not certain what data is current, it's tricky to get info on the latest work, I believe that was back in 2012, this article is from 2014 (http://m.phys.org/news/2014-11-largest-factored-quantum-device.html) Have we seen any public data from 2016? Not to exclude what might be classified. Although it can't run Shors Algorithm, D-Wave is now over 1000 qbits

Comment: @stujo: same principles will rule when all of us use Quantum CPUs, as primes can keep growing, its all about finding larger, impractical for quantum CPUs, the problem exists if some use regular CPUS to create keys, and some use Quantum CPUs to break those. The power of quantum CPUs, as I understand is that it uses qbits, each qbit can have 3 values, thus the new technology is base 3 not base 2. a 64 qbits CPU would have 3^64 combinations in a word. Don't know how it impacts performance.

Comment: @stujo Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Comment: @juanmf: your understanding of quantum computing is *completely* wrong. It has absolutely nothing to do with having 3 values, that would be utterly uninteresting. The details are very complex, but the effect is that some quantum algorithms can solve problems in a lower Big-O complexity than "normal" algorithms on non-quantum hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @MichaelBorgwardt I’d like to understand why though.. if you have any link I’d appreciate you sharing it. Regards.

Comment: @juanmf: If you really want to understand, you have to go into some rather complex physics and maths. Wikipedia would be a  good starting place: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing A short, simplified explanation would be that a quantum algorithm can perform a calculation on *all possible values* of an entire register of qbits at the same time.

Comment: @juanmf - qbit is an amazing mystery : 1) qbit can have infinite amount of values {0,1 or _anything_ between 0..1} 2) You don't know qbit value until you check it 3) Funniest part - checking qbit value changes it's value

Answer (score 142):

Simple? Yup.

If you multiply two large prime numbers, you get a huge non-prime number with only two (large) prime factors.

Factoring that number is a non-trivial operation, and that fact is the source of a lot of Cryptographic algorithms. See [one-way functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) for more information.

Addendum:
Just a bit more explanation.  The product of the two prime numbers can be used as a public key, while the primes themselves as a private key.  Any operation done to data that can only be undone by knowing one of the two factors will be non-trivial to unencrypt.

Comment: Also worth noting that, in addition to the factorization problem, a lot of modern crypto also (or instead) relies on the discrete logarithm problem. Both are "one-way" functions: it's easy to take known-inputs and compute an answer, but hard to take an answer and compute those inputs.

Comment: Linking this explanation to the term "one-way function" would be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function

Comment: But if public key can be used to encrypt why it can not be used to do the opposite?

Comment: @jayarjo But who said it can't be used to decrypt?  Welcome to the world of digital signatures (produced by private keys), publicly verifiable using public keys!

Answer (score 48):

Here is a very simple and common example.

The [RSA encryption algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) which is commonly used in secure commerce web sites, is based on the fact that it is easy to take two (very large) prime numbers and multiply them, while it is extremely hard to do the opposite - meaning: take a very large number, given which it has only two prime factors, and find them.

Comment: Just FYI, the number you get from multiplying two primes is called a semi-prime.

Comment: How large is the prime numbers used in RSA?

Answer (score 18):

It's not so much the prime numbers themselves that are important, but the algorithms that work with primes. In particular, finding the factors of a number (any number).

As you know, any number has at least two factors. Prime numbers have the unique property in that they have exactly two factors: 1 and themselves.

The reason factoring is so important is mathematicians and computer scientists don't know how to factor a number without simply trying every possible combination. That is, first try dividing by 2, then by 3, then by 4, and so forth. If you try to factor a prime number--especially a very large one--you'll have to try (essentially) every possible number between 2 and that large prime number. Even on the fastest computers, it will take years (even centuries) to factor the kinds of prime numbers used in cryptography.

It is the fact that we don't know how to efficiently factor a large number that gives cryptographic algorithms their strength. If, one day, someone figures out how to do it, all the cryptographic algorithms we currently use will become obsolete. This remains an open area of research.

Comment: You actually only have to test the prime numbers up to the square root of the number you are trying to factor.

Comment: I know. It was a detail I "overlooked" in the name of simplicity.

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker Would you mind explaining why this is? I don't really understand.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ say `n` is not prime & `n = a * b`. If `a > sqrt(n)`, `b` must be smaller and vice-versa, else `a * b > n` itself which would negate our initial claim. So to check for prime, we only check until sqrt.

Answer (score 13):

Because nobody knows a fast algorithm to factorize an integer into its prime factors. Yet, it is very easy to check if a set of prime factors multiply to a certain integer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it is already possible in fast time to find out IF a number is prime.

Comment: There's a missing "if the prime factors are large" here.

Comment: @Ben: It isn't missing. The problem is hard in general. Note that problems that are hard in general may have easy cases. In this case, small primes are by no means the only easy cases.

Comment: Nobody knows "in public". It might be possible that the intelligence agencies of the various world governments have techniques they aren't sharing. They hire huge numbers of math grads. For example the NSA secretly promoted random prime generation by "Dual EC_DRBG", which they knew was weak, as part of a standard crypto scheme for public use. http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/10/government-announces-steps-to-restore-confidence-on-encryption-standards

Comment: don: the snowden documents seem to reveal that that isn't the case. they draw a pretty conclusive picture that, (by and large, there could be corners), the NSA cannot decrypt encrypted data through special math magic only they know. Schneier discussed the issue extensively.

Answer (score 12):

There are some good resources for ramping up on crypto. Here's one:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/crypto/firstcrypto.aspx

From that page:

> In the most commonly used public-key
>   cryptography system, invented by Ron
>   Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Len Adleman in
>   1977, both the public and the private
>   keys are derived from a pair of large
>   prime numbers according to a
>   relatively simple mathematical
>   formula. In theory, it might be
>   possible to derive the private key
>   from the public key by working the
>   formula backwards. But only the
>   product of the large prime numbers is
>   public, and factoring numbers of that
>   size into primes is so hard that even
>   the most powerful supercomputers in
>   the world cant break an ordinary
>   public key.

Bruce Schneier's book *Applied Cryptography* is another. I highly recommend that book; it's fun reading.

Answer (score 9):

To be a little more concrete about how RSA uses properties of prime numbers, the RSA algorithm depends critically upon [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Theorem), which states that for relatively prime numbers "a" and "N", a^e is congruent to 1 [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) N, where e is the [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of N.

Where do primes come into that?  To compute the Euler's totient function of N efficiently requires knowing the prime factorization of N.  In the case of the RSA algorithm, where N = pq for some primes "p" and "q", then e = (p - 1)(q - 1) = N - p - q + 1.  But without knowing p and q, computation of e is very difficult.

More abstractly, many crypotgraphic protocols use various [trapdoor functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function), functions which are easy to compute but difficult to invert.  Number theory is a rich source of such trapdoor functions (such as multiplication of large prime numbers), and prime numbers are absolutely central to number theory.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest the book [A Mathematical Journey In Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0761123849). The book has a nice down to earth feel, which is surprising, since it is about cryptography.  The book summarizes Sarah Flannery’s journey from learning puzzles as a child to creating the Cayley-Purser (CP) algorithm at the age of 16. It gives an amazingly detailed explanation of one way functions, number theory, and prime numbers and how they relate to cryptography.

What makes this book even more specific to your question is Sarah tried to implement a new public key algorithm using matrix's. It was much faster then using prime numbers but a loop hole was found that could exploit it. It turns out her algorithm was better used as a private encryption mechanism. The book is a great testament to using prime numbers for encryption as it has stood the test of time and the challenges of very smart individuals.

Answer (score 6):

One more resource for you.  [Security Now! episode 30](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-030.htm)(~30 minute podcast, link is to the transcript) talks about cryptography issues, and explains why primes are important.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a mathematician or cryptician, so here's an outside observation in layman's terms (no fancy equations, sorry).

This whole thread is filled with explanations about **HOW** primes are used in cryptography, it's hard to find anyone in this thread explaining in an easy way **WHY** primes are used ... most likely because everyone takes that knowledge for granted.

Only looking at the problem from the outside can generate a reaction like; but if they use the sums of two primes, why not create a list of all possible sums any two primes can generate?

On this [site](http://www.prime-numbers.org/) there's a list of **455,042,511** primes, where the highest primes is **9,987,500,000** (**10** digits).
The largest known prime (as of feb 2015) is **2 to the power of 257,885,161 − 1** which is **17,425,170** digits.
 This means that there's no point keeping a list of all the known primes and much less all their possible sums. It's easier to take a number and check if it's a prime.

Calculating big primes in itself is a monumental task, so **reverse calculating** two primes that has been multiplied with each other both cryptographers and mathematicians would say is **hard enough** ... today.

Comment: Only your last paragraph is really valid. The argument of sums can be said for any composite number too (there is a large range [technically infinitely large], storage of all sums is infeasible/stupid). Also the sums of primes doesn't hold that much relevance in cryptography, more important (usually, as in the case of RSA) is their product. Also, by **reverse calculating** you probably mean **factoring**. That'll probably help with what you mean there.

Answer (score 4):

Cryptographic algorithms generally rely for their security on having a "difficult problem". Most modern algorithms seem to use the factoring of very large numbers as their difficult problem - if you multiply two large numbers together, computing their factors is "difficult" (i.e. time-consuming). If those two numbers are prime numbers, then there is only one answer, which makes it even more difficult, and also guarantees that when you find the answer, it's the right one, not some other answer that just happens to give the same result.

Answer (score 4):

I think what are important in cryptography are not primes itself, but it is the **difficulty** of *prime factorization problem*

Suppose you have very very large integer which is known to be product of two primes m and n, it is not easy to find what are m and n. Algorithm such as RSA depends on this fact.

By the way, there is a [published paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027) on algorithm which can "solve" this prime factorization problem in acceptable time using quantum computer. So newer algorithms in cryptography may not rely on this "difficulty" of prime factorization anymore when quantum computer comes to town :)

Answer (score 3):

Because factorization algorithms speed up considerably with each factor found.  Making both private keys prime ensures the first factor found will also be the last.  Ideally, both private keys will also be nearly equal in value since only the strength of the weaker key matters.

Comment: This look a bit redundant to me. A part from the weaker key part which could be commented to the top answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Prime numbers are mainly used in cryptography since it consumes considerable time in determining whether a given number is prime number or not. For the hacker if any algorithm takes lot of time to break the code it becomes useless for them

Comment: Figuring out if a number is a prime is cheap and we need it to be cheap. How else would we know that we chose primes as our prime factors in RSA or a prime as modulus in finite field crypto? What's expensive is factoring a large *composite* number into its large prime factors.