# Boolean.hashCode()

Tags: java, boolean, hashcode

The `hashCode()` method of class Boolean is implemented like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return value ? 1231 : 1237;
}
```

Why does it use 1231 and 1237? Why not something else?

Comment: These two numbers are sufficiently big prime numbers. Please read the [article on Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) on Wikipedia for further info.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

1231 and 1237 are just two (sufficiently large) **arbitrary prime numbers**. Any other two large prime numbers would do fine.

**Why primes?**
Suppose for a second that we picked composite numbers (non-primes), say 1000 and 2000. When inserting booleans into a hash table, *true* and *false* would go into bucket `1000 % N` resp `2000 % N` (where `N` is the number of buckets).

Now notice that

- `1000 %  8` same bucket as `2000 %  8`
- `1000 % 10` same bucket as `2000 % 10`
- `1000 % 20` same bucket as `2000 % 20`
- ....

in other words, it would lead to *many collisions*.

This is because the factorization of 1000 (2<sup>3</sup>, 5<sup>3</sup>) and the factorization of 2000 (2<sup>4</sup>, 5<sup>3</sup>) have so many common factors. Thus prime numbers are chosen, since they are unlikely to have any common factors with the bucket size.

**Why *large* primes. Wouldn't 2 and 3 do?**
When computing hash codes for composite objects it's common to add the hash codes for the components. If too small values are used in a hash set with a large number of buckets there's a risk of ending up with an uneven distribution of objects.

**Do collisions matter? Booleans just have two different values anyway?**
Maps can contain booleans together with other objects. Also, as pointed out by Drunix, a common way to create hash functions of composite objects is to reuse the subcomponents hash code implementations in which case it's good to return large primes.

**Related questions:**

- [Why use a prime number in hashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode)
- [What is a sensible prime for hashcode calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835976/what-is-a-sensible-prime-for-hashcode-calculation)
- [Why does Java's hashCode() in String use 31 as a multiplier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier/299748)

Comment: `why not other large prime nos used?`   Here is list of all prime no? http://mindprod.com/jgloss/primes.html under 10,000, can you please explain this

Comment: I suppose these are sufficiently large. To get a gcd greater than 1, you'd need at least `2*1231 = 2462` buckets. Are collisions a problem in such a situation?

Comment: Interesting though that they are not really "fairly large" considering what can fit into an int. I suppose they are just big enough to work well with the JDK Hashtable, but still small enough to minimize calculation costs.

Comment: Yes, it struck me too that they're not *that* large. But do you believe there is a higher cost with larger primes?

Comment: @Thilo you'd need a multiple of 1231*1237 = 1,522,747 buckets before they would collide, that is plenty large enough

Comment: I would say that leading to collisions with bucket count is not really a problem with boolean, but more the common construction on how we get the hascode of a composite object, namely by multiplying the hashcodes of the components with some constants and adding them up.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I don't follow why you would have collisions if your bucket size is 6 and your primes are 2 and 3. Surely 2 % 6 != 3 % 6 and your two boolean values will only ever go into two buckets.

Comment: @Chris, made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Answer updated.

Comment: @aioobe Don't you think 121 and 127 would be large enough, and better choice as they are cached ? Is there any indication in the spec of a lowest *"correct"* prime number ?

Comment: You want hash codes to be as evenly spread across Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE. When aggregating hash codes (for instance by multiplying by "sub" hashcodes) 121 and 127 wouldn't "reach" that far. I realize that 1231 and 1237 doesn't reach *that* much further, but that's the best explanation I got.

Comment: I understand that we need large enough prime numbers. But still not understand why not larger than 1231 and 1237 to cover the integer range. I think it might be about performance trade-off. But basically, how to measure "sufficiently large" and their traid-off? Did someone measure the performance before choosing these 2 numbers.

Comment: After giving it some more thought, the only way to know the exact answer is to ask the original developers. It appears that they chose some mid-range numbers to reduce the risk of overflow when aggregating multiple hashcode values for the cases they deemed common (maybe from a statistic they have at that time). However, the specific cases they chose remain unknown. Hopefully, one of them see this question and reveal the secret :).

Comment: About overflow risk: normally, it's not a problem of hashcode if implemented correctly (ex. following 31*x + y rule). But if not (inexperience developers), avoid overflow could help them a bit in reducing collisions.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to all that's said above it can also be a small easter egg from developers:

> true: 1231 => 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 7

7 - is a lucky number in European traditions;

> false: 1237 => 1 + 2 + 3 + 7 = 13

13 (aka Devil's dozen) - unlucky number.