# Why new Formatter().format("%h", false) gets 4D5?

Tags: java, boolean

According to the output, java boolean false equals to `10011010101` and true equals to 4CF, `10011001111`. I don't understand why java uses these value for boolean. And what exactly boolean is stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation for the `%h` format specifier:

> If the argument arg is `null`, then the result is `"null"`. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking `Integer.toHexString(arg.hashCode())`.

I think this speaks for itself. `false` is boxed into `Boolean.FALSE`, and that object happens to have a hash code.

Comment: And the `hashCode` for `true` is `1231`; `false` is `1237`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912303/boolean-hashcode