# C# Overriding the GetHashCode method

Tags: c#, algorithm, hashcode, state-machine

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c/5924053#5924053) example, the poster has overridden the get hash code method. I understand that this has been done in order to provide a better hash value for the returned object, to reduce the number of collisions, and therefore reduce the number of occasions it will be necessary to call `Equals()`.

What i would like to know, is how this algorithm been calculated:

```
return 17 + 31 * CurrentState.GetHashCode() + 31 * Command.GetHashCode();
```

Is there a particular reason that the numbers in question were chosen? Could i have simply picked my own numbers to put into it?

Comment: Just for info, the MS C# compiler (for anon-types) uses a seed of `-1134271262`, and a multiplier of `-1521134295`. Just sayin'

Comment: @MarcGravell: Do you have the source for that?

Comment: @DeepSpace101 ILDASM ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: I see the same `-1521134295` multiplier in ILDASM but the `seed` appears to be a composite seed (it's a random int32 multiplied by the same multiplier). So the seed's not only *NOT* prime (contrary to popular belief), it's also random based on the anon-type member names/type/count. Weird. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DeepSpace none. Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you should choose primes. This helps you to avoid getting the same hash-value for different input parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Prime numbers are usually used in hashcode computation to minimize the collisions. If you search for **hashcode** and **prime numbers** on this iste, you will find some detailed explanations on this (note that it is note language specific):

- [What is a sensible prime for hashcode calculation ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835976/what-is-a-sensible-prime-for-hashcode-calculation)
- [Why does Java's hashCode() in String use 31 as a multiplier ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier)

Answer (score 1):

You typically want to use prime numbers (as is done above) because it reduces the chance of collisions (two instances yielding same result). For more info, see: http://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers/