# How to reduce hash collisions?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable

I wrote code which reads some words and their meanings from a file and maps them to an array (make hash table). It uses polynomial hash code and a compress method.

My goal is to reduce the collisions as less as possible but I don't know how.

```
public int hashcode(Entry my){ 
    Object key=my.getKey(); 
    int sum=0 ,z=33; 
    char[] chars = new char[key.toString().length()]; 
    chars=key.toString().toCharArray(); 
    for(int i=0; i < chars.length; i++){ 
         sum += (chars[i])*Math.pow(z,i);
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

and this is my compress method (for an array by size 100):

```
public int compress(int hashcode){ 
    return hashcode%100; 
}
```

Should I change my compress method or there are ways which may help me?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: what is the size of the table? make it a prime number. use prime numbers within hash code. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980117/hash-table-why-size-should-be-prime

Comment: Why don't you use String's hashCode(), and a standard HashMap? Show us your code.

Comment: Math.pow is very excessive, I suggest you use iterative multiplication instead.

Comment: @JBNizet:I've not allowed to use hashCode().

Comment: I do appreciate everyone who answered me.I could reduce collisions from 95 to 50.It's still a lot but solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a perfect hash function, unfortunately, as far as I know, such a hash does not exist :)
Another thing to point out is that the performance of hash functions also varies by the type of result you want to achieve; what I mean is that a hash function might perform excellent for "storing" phone numbers but provide poor results for storing the contact's name.

From a quick look over your code I'd say that you're hash function is over complicated.
First I'd like to point out a  problem with your current algorithm: this line 'sum+=(chars[i])*Math.pow(z,i);' will return values that are way beyond the integer range for words that are more than 4-5 characters long (just a guess). You'll probably say it's ok because it will overflow and so on but the truth is it won't because the sum+= syntax actually hides a type cast (try writing it as sum=sum+) and in such cases the sum will have the value of Integer.MAX_VALUE. This is probably why your algorithm is slow right now.

If I were you, for the purpose of a dictionary (which seems to be what you are trying to do)  and assuming that Entry#getKey() is of type String, I would probably just go with:

```
public int hashcode(Entry my) {
    return my.getKey().hashCode();
}
```

If you still want to come up with your own hash function why not go with something more simpler like: [word length + char code of first X letters + char code of the last letter] where you adapt X so the result will fit into an int. Just an idea :)