# Create Hash Value on a List?

Tags: c#, collections, .net-4.0, hash, queue

I have a `List<MyRichObject>` with 50 instances in it. Each of the instances has 1 or 2 unique properties, but in a way they are all unique because there is only one at position in the list, etc.

I would like to come up with a unique way to "hash" this List so it is unique from all of the other Lists. Is there a smart way to do that in .NET 4?

The purpose is to create a kind of "monniker" for the Lists so they can be dumped into a queue and found later based on their unique value.

Thanks.

Comment: basically you ... sort the list ... dump each member to a byte[], join all the byte[] ... hash the big byte[] with a sha2 or your favorite hashing function and you are done

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
public static int GetSequenceHashCode<T>(this IList<T> sequence)
{
    const int seed = 487;
    const int modifier = 31;

    unchecked
    {
        return sequence.Aggregate(seed, (current, item) =>
            (current*modifier) + item.GetHashCode());
    }            
}
```

### Why bother with another answer?

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7278155/243557) can give dangerously inaccurate results if you have multiple items in the list with the same hash code. For example consider these inputs:

```
var a = new []{ "foo" };
var b = new []{ "foo", "bar" };
var c = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam" };
var d = new []{ "seenoevil", "hearnoevil", "speaknoevil" };
```

These all produce different results suggesting they are all unique collections. Great! Now let's try with a duplicate:

```
var e = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam" };
```

`GetSequenceHashCode` should produce the same result for both `c` and `e` - and it does. So far so good. Now let's try with items out of sequence:

```
var f = new []{ "spam", "bar", "foo" };
```

Uh oh... `GetSequenceHashCode` indicates that `f` is equal to both `c` and `e` which it is not. Why is this happening? Break it down into the actual hash code values first, using `c` as an example:

```
int hashC = "foo".GetHashCode() ^ 
            "bar".GetHashCode() ^ 
            "spam".GetHashCode();
```

Since the exact numbers here aren't really important and for the sake of clearer demonstration let's pretend the hash codes of the three strings are `foo=8`, `bar=16` and `spam=32`. So:

```
int hashC = 8 ^ 16 ^ 32;
```

or to break it down into binary representation:

```
8 ^ 16 ^ 32 == 56;

//  8 = 00001000
//  ^
// 16 = 00010000
//  ^
// 32 = 00100000
//  =
// 56   00111000
```

Now you should see why the order of items in the list is overlooked by this implementation, i.e. `8^16^32 = 16^8^32 = 32^16^8` etc.

Secondly there's an issue with duplicates. Even if you assume that having the same contents in a different sequence is OK (which is not an approach I would encourage), I don't think anyone will argue the below behaviour is desirable. Let's try variations with duplicates within each list.

```
var a = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam" };
var b = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam", "foo" };
var c = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam", "foo", "foo" };
var d = new []{ "foo", "bar", "spam", "foo", "foo", "spam", "foo", "spam", "foo" };
```

While `a` and `b` generate different seqeuence hashes, `GetSequenceHashCode` suggests that `a`, `c` and `d` are all the same. Why?

If you XOR a number with itself you essentially cancel it out, i.e.

```
8 ^ 8 == 0;

//  8 = 00001000
//  ^
//  8 = 00001000
//  =
//  0 = 00000000
```

XOR by the same number again gives you the original result, i.e.

```
8 ^ 8 ^ 8 == 8;

//  8 = 00001000
//  ^
//  8 = 00001000
//  ^
//  8 = 00001000
//  =
//  8 = 00001000
```

So if we look at `a` and `c` again, substituting the simplified hash codes:

```
var a = new []{ 8, 16, 32 };
var c = new []{ 8, 16, 32, 8, 8 };
```

the hash codes are caclulated as:

```
int hashA = 8 ^ 16 ^ 32;         // = 56
int hashC = 8 ^ 16 ^ 32 ^ 8 ^ 8; // = 56
                       // ↑   ↑ 
                       // these two cancel each other out
```

and likewise with `d` where each pair of `foo` and `spam` cancels itself out.

Comment: Great answer.  Changing my implementation to be an extension of IEnumerable to include other collections.  I am curious where the seed and modifier values came from or if they're really arbitrary so long as the modifier is not 0 or 1.

Comment: 31 and 487 are both prime numbers. Why use primes? This is already covered extensively in other answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus

Answer (score 3):

Does the hash have to be representative of the list's contents? In other words will you use the hash to determine potential equality?  If not then just create a new Guid and use that.

If the identifier does need to represent the contents of the list then you can either generate a hashcode based on the contents of the list (this will be inefficient as you will be unable to cache this value as the list's contents may change) or forgo the hash altogether and use `Enumerable.SequenceEquals` to determine equality.

---

Here is an example of how I would implement getting a hash code for a `List<T>`. First of all, if you are going to get a hash code for a particular object your really ought to make sure that object will not change. If that object does change then your hash code is no longer any good.

The best way to work with a list that can be "frozen" (meaning no items added or removed after a certain point) is to call `AsReadOnly`. This will give you a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. The implementation below hinges on a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` just to be safe so keep that in mind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var seqOne = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var seqTwo = new List<int> { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        var seqOneCode = seqOne.AsReadOnly().GetSequenceHashCode();
        var seqTwoCode = seqTwo.AsReadOnly().GetSequenceHashCode();

        Console.WriteLine(seqOneCode == seqTwoCode);
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static int GetSequenceHashCode<T>(this ReadOnlyCollection<T> sequence)
    {
        return sequence
            .Select(item => item.GetHashCode())
            .Aggregate((total, nextCode) => total ^ nextCode);
    }
}
```

---

Oh, one last thing - make sure that your `MyRichObject` type [has a good `GetHashCode` implementation itself](http://togaroga.com/2010/03/all-types-are-not-compared-equally-part-2/) otherwise your hash code for the list will potentially yield a lot of false positives upon comparison.

Comment: Thanks. This is not for determining equality, it is for making a value which is unique based on the contents of the list. I make 500 of these lists and drop them in a queue, I want to inspect the queue and make sure everything in the queue is distinct.

Comment: @Snowy - I understand but checking for distinct items in a queue is a matter of equality. The way you know that an item is distinct is if it does not equal any other item. Do these lists ever change once they are placed on the queue?

Comment: Thanks for helping me think through this. No the lists do not change once they get into the queue. I believe I do want to create a hash based on each List's contents.

Comment: Awesome. I was doing something convoluted with serialization and getting a hash on that. Your stuff looks much better. Thanks.