# Generating a random number related to input parameters

Tags: c#, random

```
public float randomNumber(float x, float y, Random rnd)
{
    //Return a random number between 0 - 1
}
```

So my problem is I need the random number to be related to x and y. If I pass in x = 10, y = 5 and I get out 0.34567f when I pass in x = 10, y = 5 a second time I need a result of 0.34567f again. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Based on the responses below I realize I left something out. The reason I pass in the Random object is because it has been pre-seeded elsewhere. So if I pass in x = 10, y = 5 for a random object with a seed of 50 and get out 0.34567f doing the same thing with a Random object with a seed of 51 should give me something different.

Comment: Probably overkill, but you can use a cryptographic hash. SHA1 or MD5 or something. That's guaranteed to get you the same output for the same input.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really need a *random* number, you just need a hash based on two floats.  Searching on those terms will likely give you better results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use them as a seed:

```
int seed = 
    BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(
        x * 17 + y
    ));
new Random(seed).NextDouble();
```

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion you meant to shift and not multiply. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @lc no, you multiply by a prime number then add them together so passing in 1 for x and 2 for y does not produce the same number as 2 for x and 1 for y. see [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus) for a detailed explanation of why you choose a prime number.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the explanation. But in this case you'll get a collision with (2,17) and (3,0), not that it maybe matters.

Comment: Thanks! This works if I add in a random value from the seeded random.

Comment: @lc Yes, collisions are impossible to prevent due to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). In simple terms If you have 11 things and 10 boxes to put it in then somthing is going to have 2 things in one box (in context to seeding Random we have `int.MAX_INT` boxes (per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) Random takes the absolute value of `seed` so `-1234` and `1234` seed the random number generator with the same values.))

Answer (score 2):

Use x and y as seed value

```
public float RandomNumber(float x, float y)
{
    var rnd = new Random(x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode());
    return (float)rnd.NextDouble();
}
```

---

Note: The `^` operator performs an XOR operation on the bits of x and y.

---

**UPDATE** (in response to  SLaks's,  Servy's and  Scott Chamberlain's comments)

Your "random number" is not a random number at all. What you probably need is a hash code

```
public Hash(float x, float y)
{
    unchecked {
        return Math.Abs((527 + x) * 31 + y) % 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile.  Also, it would be symmetric around the origin.

Comment: It seems that the OP really just needs a hash.  While this technically is a hash, it's problem not the best (and certainly not the most efficient) way to go about it.

Comment: For those who do not know "symmetric around the origin" means `x = 1, y = 2` will produce the same result as `x = 2, y = 1`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you really need is a hash, not a random number.  If you needed a *sequence* of random numbers based on two floats then I would suggest using those two floats to make a seed, but when you only want a single value that's both a lot less efficient, and also not particularly great for hashes.  You could try something like this.

```
public float GetHashCode(float x, float y)
{
    float somePrimeNumber = 17.0
    return Math.Abs(1.0 / (x.GetHashCode() * somePrimeNumber + y.GetHashCode() + 1));
}
```

Comment: `//Return a random number between 0 - 1`