# what is the significance of modulo 10^9+7 used in codechef and spoj problems?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

I was working on [a problem](http://www.codechef.com/SEPT14/problems/CHEFLR) which requires output as "For each line output the answer modulo 10^9+7". Why is *modulo 10^9+7* included in the problem? What is its significance?

I'm not looking for a solution to the problem; only the significance of that particular constant.

Comment: Are you asking what the value of the number is (1000000007), or how modular arithmetic works?

Comment: I am asking what it means in the problem's context.See this http://www.codechef.com/SEPT14/problems/CHEFLR . I am not asking for a solution to that problem but just this modulo 10^9+7. @MikeSeymour

Comment: If you're asking whether 10^9+7 is some special number that's relevant to the problem--I don't think so.  I think the problem setter just sort of came up with it at random.

Comment: OK, after seeing @tmyklebu's answer, I can see that it's not quite random.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the idea of doing x mod 1000000007?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578376/whats-the-idea-of-doing-x-mod-1000000007)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problems ask for results modulo primes because the alternatives, namely asking for a floating-point result giving the "high-order bits" and asking for the whole result, aren't always what the problem setter is looking for.

- These problems are often "find and implement a recurrence" problems.  The low-order bits will often tell you whether the recurrence you found is right.
- There may be a special trick for the "high-order bits" problem, perhaps based on a clever analytic approximation.
- The reason people don't often ask for the whole result is that this requires the contestant to implement big-number arithmetic.
- Problem setters usually don't want unexpected tricks to crack their problems for "the wrong reasons."

10^9+7 winds up being a pretty good choice of prime.  It is a "safe prime."  What that means:

10^9+7 is a prime number.  This means that the "Chinese remainder trick" doesn't apply; if you're trying to work something out modulo a product of two primes, say pq, then you can work it out modulo p and modulo q and use the extended Euclidean algorithm to put the pieces together.

More than that, 10^9+6, which is 10^9+7-1, is twice a prime.  So the multiplicative group modulo 10^9+7 doesn't decompose into small things and hence no Chinese-remainder-like trick applies there.

Comment: Side note:  I'd love it if people asked for the high-order bits instead of the low-order bits in enumeration problems.  There's something of an art to finding good analytic approximations to these sorts of problems and I think it's underappreciated in programming contests.

Answer (score 2):

In some problems the answers are *very* big numbers, but forcing you to implement long arighmetics is not the purpose of the problem authors. Therefore they ask you to calculate answer modulo some number, like `1000000007`, so you don't have to implement long arithmetics, but the answer is still verifiable.

Comment: So , it means I have to modulus the output (in this case it's the number present at node) with 10^9+7?

Comment: @ShubhamMarathia I haven't read the specific problem, but in general - yes.

Comment: That would help I guess.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If it was asked to give answer as modulo 10^9 you could mask the bits easily but to make problems more tough a number such as 10^9+7 is choosen