# How can I scan a number having upto 10^18 digits in C

Tags: c

No data type can store such large number. Using array
`int a[pow(10,pow(10,18))]` again won't do the job because `pow()` returns `double` and `double` can't store `10^(10^18)`.

Anyone having any idea?

I'm trying to solve [the following problem](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL18B/problems/WGHTNUM):

Consider an integer with N
digits (in decimal notation, without leading zeroes) D<sub>1</sub>,D<sub>2</sub>,D<sub>3</sub>,…,D<sub>N</sub>. Here, D<sub>1</sub> is the most significant digit and D<sub>N</sub> the least significant. The weight of this integer is defined as:

∑ i=2 -> N (D<sub>i</sub>−D<sub>i−1</sub>).

You are given integers N and W. Find the number of positive integers with N digits (without leading zeroes) and weight equal to W. Compute this number modulo 10<sup>9</sup>+7.

Input:

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first and only line of each test case contains two space-separated integers N and W  denoting the number of digits and the required weight.

Output:

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer — the number of N-digit positive integers with weight W, modulo 10<sup>9</sup>+7.

Constraints:

- 1≤T≤10<sup>5</sup>
- 2≤N≤10<sup>18</sup>
- |W|≤300

Comment: What are you trying to do with numbers of that size?

Comment: if each digit is one byte then that would take 1 million TB. So you cant

Comment: "Store" it in whatever symbolic form you're using to describe it now and operate on that representation?

Comment: maybe `long double`... or some BIGINT, but whatever you will never have enough memory and array size can't be floating number or BIGINT. You max will always be `SIZE_MAX`

Comment: char* for storing? With some conversion of course.

Comment: How big do you think 10^18 is??   What is the ***real*** problem you are trying to solve, because this problem is not solvable within this universe.

Comment: More to the point, are you really asking about 10^(10^18) ??

Comment: I guess this isn't as bad as [iterating all GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029651/fastest-way-in-c-sharp-to-iterate-through-all-guids-possible). (10k link)

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/APRIL18B/problems/WGHTNUM in this question N is the number of digits and it can be 10^18(see constraints)

Comment: @UtkarshPandey That's asking for 10^18, meaning 1,000,000,000,000,000,000. You're asking for 10^10^18 which is so large I can't write it down here.

Comment: @schwern that's just 18 digits. In the problem, N is the NUMBER of DIGITS and it can be 10^18

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to represent numbers that big - this might give some clues about how to represent them? 10^18 digits is more than you could store in about 370 PB of RAM.

Comment: I wonder if its a mis-wording, it does say *"Consider an integer with N digits"* and later *"2 ≤ N ≤ 10^18"* which sounds like it matches the question to me

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the number of atoms in the universe?

Comment: @Schwern No, N is the number of digits. But the algorithm they are meaning is obviously not asking to store these. Could be a mistake in the question too...

Comment: You don't need to store a number of that size.  Look closely at the definition for the weight.

Comment: @UtkarshPandey I suspect you're supposed to solve the problem without actually storing 10^10^18.

Comment: Deja-vu, second post I've seen with 'modulo 10^9+7' in it.  It's not something you forget easily...

Comment: Oh look!  Entering 'modulo 10^9+7' into a popular search engine gives 'About 48,600,000 results'.  Maybe one of those could help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the significance of modulo 10^9+7 used in codechef and spoj problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689186/what-is-the-significance-of-modulo-1097-used-in-codechef-and-spoj-problems)

Comment: You need to use your creativity to find a way to solve this problem without iterating over all the 10¹⁸-digit numbers.  That's really the point of the challenge, so it's not appropriate to spoon-feed the answer here.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to store a number with 10^18 digits.  Look at the definition of the weight:

∑ i=2 -> N (D<sub>i</sub>−D<sub>i−1</sub>)

Each element in the sum is the difference of two consecutive digits.

Let's take for example a 4 digit number whose digits are D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub>, D<sub>3</sub>, D<sub>4</sub>.  Then the sum is:

(D<sub>2</sub> - D<sub>1</sub>) + (D<sub>3</sub> - D<sub>2</sub>) + (D<sub>4</sub> - D<sub>3</sub>)

Reording the operands:

D<sub>4</sub> - D<sub>3</sub> + D<sub>3</sub> - D<sub>2</sub> + D<sub>2</sub> - D<sub>1</sub>

You'll see that all but the first and last digits cancel out!  So the whole sum is D<sub>4</sub> - D<sub>1</sub>.  In fact, for any number of digits N, the sum is:

D<sub>N</sub> - D<sub>1</sub>

So only the first and the last digits are relevant.  You should be able to figure out the rest from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries for handling these sorts of problems, like [The GNU
Multiple Precision
Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/):

> **What is GMP?**
>
> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface.
>
> The main target applications for GMP are cryptography applications and research, Internet security applications, algebra systems, computational algebra research, etc.

But 10^18 would take a *huge* (and effectively impossible) amount of memory (if my math is correct: 2.881 EiB).

Comment: 10^18 is way bigger than that.  It is impossible on any single modern computer.  It would require a massive distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

The [referenced problem](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL18B/problems/WGHTNUM) takes input from `2 ≤ N ≤ 10^18`. That isn't 10^18 digits (or 10^10^18 which is absurdly enormous) but 18 digits or 2 to 1,000,000,000,000,000,000. This will fit inside a 64 bit integer, signed or unsigned.

Use [`int64_t` from stdint.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h).

10^18 is pushing the limits of 64 bit integers, probably why they chose it. Anything larger should use an [arbitrary precision math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

...but there are limits. Simply storing such a number would take about 1 million gigabytes. So while the problem is about solving for numbers with 10^18 digits, I strongly suspect you're not supposed to solve it by actually storing those numbers. There's some mathematical technique you're supposed to apply.

Comment: No! N is the number of digits. According to the original problem at least.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm pretty sure you're supposed to solve the problem without actually storing 10^10^18.

Comment: That's for sure. But your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Part of asking an expert is finding out you're asking the wrong question. :)

Comment: Again, everything but the last two paragraphs of your answer is plainly wrong with the relation to the question. I don't know how it is getting upvoted.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I could tell them you can't store 10^10^18 and that would be a technically correct answer to their stated question. But it doesn't solve their problem. Look into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more.

Comment: No! This is not the problem with the answer. The problem that you give a wrong interpretation of a well defined question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168585/discussion-between-schwern-and-eugene-sh).