# using ``1ll<<(N-1)`` to assign a large number of value to a long long int variable

Tags: c++, arrays, bitwise-operators, unsigned-long-long-int

The question I saw was stated: You are given an array **A** of size **N**. An element **Ai** is said to be charged if its value(**Ai**) is greater than or equal to **Ki** and **Ki** is the total number of subsets of the array **A**, that contains an element **Ai**.

The logic is simply the number of times a number comes as a subset is 2^N-1 times. But in some test cases, N was 4000+. so, 2^N-1 will be way beyond any variable type can hold but in editorial, the writer used `1ll<<(N-1)`. I know the left shift operator is `X<<Y = X*2^Y`. But what is this 1ll? And how is it able to store such large value?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define M 1000000007

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  int T;
  cin >> T;
  while (T--) {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    long long arr[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      cin >> arr[i];
    if (N >= 64)
      cout << 0 << endl;
    else {
      long long val = (1ll << (N - 1));
      long long ans = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (arr[i] >= val)
          ans = (ans + arr[i] % M) % M;
      cout << ans << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

`1<<N-1` explains **2^N-1** but does the 1ll means that it can take upto long long and `long long val = 1ll<<N-1`; means it can go upto 128bit?

Comment: Two things: First of all C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), though some compilers add it as a non-portable extensions. Secondly please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `long long` is a 64-bit type on current platforms, so `1ll << N-1` can't go above 64 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is this `1ll`?

The `1ll` is an [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). `1` is an  an *decimal literal* and `ll` is an *integer suffix*. The suffix `ll` means that the type of the integer literal is `long long int`. The `1` means that the value of the literal is, well, `1`.

> And how is it able to store such large value?

I think you are asking about the line:

```
long long val = (1ll << (N - 1));
```

Because of the `if (N >= 64) .. else` before, we know that `N < 64`. So the maximum number could be:

```
1ll << 63 - 1   =
1ll << 62       =
0x4000000000000000
```

Which is just a number that fits in `long long int` type. The `long long int` type has at least 64 bits.

Without the `ll` suffix, the `1` would have the type `int`. On architectures where `int` type is narrower then 64 bits, ex. 16 bits, then undefined behavior would happen. Left shifting a variable by a number greater or equal to the length in bits of the left operant is undefined behavior, see ex. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860538/unexpected-c-c-bitwise-shift-operators-outcome).

If you are asking about the line :

```
ans = (ans + arr[i] % M) % M;
```

It is  calculating the sum modulo `#define M 1000000007`. It is common to do assignments/homework that calculate sum modulo this number, see ex [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578376/whats-the-idea-of-doing-x-mod-1000000007) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=1000000007). The algorithm calculates the sum modulo 1000000007, not the whole number, that's why it is able to store it inside `long long` variable.