# Is a cryptographic hash susceptible to clustering on a hash table of non-prime modulus?

Tags: data-structures, hash, language-agnostic, hashtable

I have read the question "[Why should hash functions use a prime number modulus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus)" and understand it's answer.

I am wondering if a hash table that uses a cryptographic hash function such as `SHA2` would experience more clustering if the table had a non-prime modulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cryptographic hash function should certainly be uniformly distributed in any modulus, prime or composite. If there were significant clustering for any modulus value, that would reduce the function's collision-resistance.

The "usual advice" about using primes does not expect the prime to be 2, or any other smallish number. On the whole, the problem with using a composite is not so much that it's composite as that it has a small prime divisor, like 2.