# Choosing radix and modulus prime in rabin-karp rolling hash

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

The hash function is explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)

It says, "The choice of a and n is critical to get good hashing;" and refers to a Linear congruential generator article that doesn't feel relevant. I cant figure out how the values are chosen. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's really no recipe for it. You have to experiment, or use what others have already proven to work well in general or in a particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of this algorithm is that a nonzero polynomial of degree at most *d* has at most *d* zeros. Each length-*k* string has its own associated polynomial of degree *k* - 1, and we screen for possible matches by subtracting the polynomials of the strings in question and evaluating at *a*. If the strings are equal, then the result is always zero. If the strings are not equal, then the result is zero if and only if *a* is one of the zeros of the polynomial difference (this is the fact that puts the primality requirement on *n*, as the integers mod *n* otherwise would not be a field).

In theory, at least, we want *a* to be random so that an oblivious adversary cannot create false positives with any frequency. If we don't expect trouble, then it might be better to choose *a* so that multiplication by *a* is cheap (e.g., the binary expansion of *a* has a small number of one bits). Nevertheless, some choices are bad on typical string sets (e.g., *a* = 1). We want *n* to be large enough to avoid false positives (probability (*k* - 1)/*n*) by random chance but small enough and preferably of a special form so that the modulo computations are efficient.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of well chosen n? (modulo)

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample 2^31-1 is a good choice for many applications. You can do the multiply portably using 64-bit arithmetic, and the modulo operation can be optimized to avoid division (and your compiler may be able to do this for you, e.g., clang on my laptop emits assembly code with no divide operations).

Comment: Won't that overflow with the inverse-mod you need to take for the Rabin Karp optimization?

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample The inverse mod is a number between 1 and n-1, so I'm not sure why that would happen.

Comment: OK I found the issue. If p is that high, you can end up with negative numbers inyour rolling hash. So it makes sense to scale p (or the maximum value of p ** base) https://youtu.be/w6nuXg0BISo?t=1984