# Why do people use hash(k) = c * k with a prime c

Tags: hash

Given an integer m, a hash function defined on `T` is a map `T -> {0, 1, 2, ..., m - 1}`. If `k` is an element of `T` and `m` is a positive integer, we denote `hash(k, m)` its hashed value.

For simplicity, most hash functions are of the form `hash(k, m) = f(k) % m` where `f` is a map from `T` to the set of integers.

In the case where `m = 2^p` (which is often used to the modulo `m` operation is cheap) and `T` is a set of integers, I have seen many people using `f(k) = c * k` with `c` being a prime number.

I understand if you want to choose a function of the form `f(k) = c * k`, you need to have `gcd(c, m) = 1` for every hash table size `m`. Even though using a prime number fits the bill, `c = 1` is also good.

So my question is the following: why do people still use `f(k) = prime * k` as their hash function? What kind of nice property does it have?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/why-is-it-best-to-use-a-prime-number-as-a-mod-in-a-hashing-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus

Comment: None of these links answer my question. For instance, in the link given by Joe, they explain why it is a good idea to use a prime for `m`. By the way, I agree with their point of view. But my question is different.

Comment: Because gcd=1, `(c*k) % (1<<n)` spreads uniformly, so it allows overflow in binary representation (all computers are binary these days), and also allows `m` to be a power of two.

Comment: @wildplasser: But k % (1 << n) spreads uniformly as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it to be prime. One of the most efficient hash functions with provable collision resistance just multiplies with a random number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Avoiding_modular_arithmetic. You do however need it to be odd.

Comment: Here `odd` means: relatively prime wrt the table size.

Comment: @wildplasser I suppose, but only because the hash function outputs `2^k` bits for some `k>0`. If we can then take that number modulo some prime, if we need to make it smaller, but usually hash-tables have a size that's a power of two anyway. Using primes for the modulo is usually important, just not for the multiplication.