# striking relationships modulo 2^32 between strings that are the same except near the end

Tags: string, hash, hashmap, hashtable

This question is a follow up to one of the answers to below question.
 [Why should hash functions use a prime number modulus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus?newreg=e5d98144a39e44d69f1af262534bc16d)

**Steve Jessop, in his answer states that "So you get striking relationships modulo 2^32 between strings that are the same except near the end."**

I tried for the last couple of days to come up with an explanation for the above statement, but I came up with nothing.

If any one of you know the explanation, please let me know.

FYI: since I don't have enough points I was not able to post this as a comment to Steve's answer.

Comment: The answer is based on a simple (and rather uncommon) additive hashfunction. The modulo-prime table size merely serves to compensate this.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please provide me an example like Steve did with a string and k=31.