# Rationale behind cpython's prime multiplier _PyHASH_MULTIPLIER

Tags: python, hash, cpython

I found this in [`pyhash.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/pyhash.h#L16). I know `_PyHASH_MULTIPLIER` is prime multiplier used for hashing but I just want to the rationale behind that prime number. I searched PEPs but didn't get anything constructive.

Thank you.

Comment: in theory, using a prime reduces the number of collisions. which you could find with a quick search...first hit: https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145217/why-should-hash-functions-use-a-prime-number-modulus , https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/why-is-it-best-to-use-a-prime-number-as-a-mod-in-a-hashing-function

Comment: @MitchWheat My question is related with python. I know the theory. Are you implying that it is random choice and any prime will do?