# Divisibility represented by Boolean logic (satisfiability)

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, satisfiability

(Copied from Math StackExchange with some modifications, tell me if this isn't the right place)

Some context: I was thinking about the feasibility of using SAT solvers to prove primality, especially of Mersenne primes, by showing that there exists no Boolean array d[1],d[2],...,d[b'] that can represent a divisor of the prime (i.e. UNSAT).

Given a Boolean list d[1],d[2],...,d[b], where d is the base-2 representation of a base-10 positive integers D, does there exist a Boolean predicate that evaluates to True if and only if 2^b−1≡0(mod D)?

(Assume `1<D<N`, and hence, `b′<b`. Also assume b is prime.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a multiplier network circuit to find two factors of the given number. The circuit is then translated by [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) to [conjunctive normal form (CNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and submitted to a SAT Solver like [Cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat), [Clasp](https://potassco.org/clasp/) or [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3).

Example circuit for factoring `17` ([bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) format):

```
BC1.0
//  P = 17
_t1 := A0 & B0;
_t2 := A1 & B0;
_t3 := A2 & B0;
_t4 := A0 & B1;
_t5 := A1 & B1;
_t6 := A2 & B1;
_t7 := A0 & B2;
_t8 := A1 & B2;
_t9 := A2 & B2;
_t10 := A0 & B3;
_t11 := A1 & B3;
_t12 := A2 & B3;
_t13 := A0 & B4;
_t14 := A1 & B4;
_t15 := A2 & B4;
_t16 := ODD(_t2, _t4);
_t17 := _t2 & _t4;
_t18 := ODD(_t3, _t5);
_t19 := _t3 & _t5;
_t20 := ODD(_t7, _t17);
_t21 := _t7 & _t17;
_t22 := ODD(_t18, _t20);
_t23 := _t18 & _t20;
_t24 := ODD(_t6, _t8);
_t25 := _t6 & _t8;
_t26 := ODD(_t10, _t19);
_t27 := _t10 & _t19;
_t28 := ODD(_t21, _t23);
_t29 := _t21 & _t23;
_t30 := ODD(_t24, _t26);
_t31 := _t24 & _t26;
_t32 := ODD(_t28, _t30);
_t33 := _t28 & _t30;
_t34 := ODD(_t9, _t11);
_t35 := _t9 & _t11;
_t36 := ODD(_t13, _t25);
_t37 := _t13 & _t25;
_t38 := ODD(_t27, _t29);
_t39 := _t27 & _t29;
_t40 := ODD(_t31, _t33);
_t41 := _t31 & _t33;
_t42 := ODD(_t34, _t36);
_t43 := _t34 & _t36;
_t44 := ODD(_t38, _t40);
_t45 := _t38 & _t40;
_t46 := ODD(_t42, _t44);
_t47 := _t42 & _t44;
_t48 := ODD(_t12, _t14);
_t49 := _t12 & _t14;
_t50 := ODD(_t35, _t37);
_t51 := _t35 & _t37;
_t52 := ODD(_t39, _t41);
_t53 := _t39 & _t41;
_t54 := ODD(_t43, _t45);
_t55 := _t43 & _t45;
_t56 := ODD(_t47, _t48);
_t57 := _t47 & _t48;
_t58 := ODD(_t50, _t52);
_t59 := _t50 & _t52;
_t60 := ODD(_t54, _t56);
_t61 := _t54 & _t56;
_t62 := ODD(_t58, _t60);
_t63 := _t58 & _t60;
_t64 := ODD(_t15, _t49);
_t65 := _t15 & _t49;
_t66 := ODD(_t51, _t53);
_t67 := _t51 & _t53;
_t68 := ODD(_t55, _t57);
_t69 := _t55 & _t57;
_t70 := ODD(_t59, _t61);
_t71 := _t59 & _t61;
_t72 := ODD(_t63, _t64);
_t73 := _t63 & _t64;
_t74 := ODD(_t66, _t68);
_t75 := _t66 & _t68;
_t76 := ODD(_t70, _t72);
_t77 := _t70 & _t72;
_t78 := ODD(_t74, _t76);
_t79 := _t74 & _t76;
_t80 := ODD(_t65, _t67);
_t81 := ODD(_t69, _t71);
_t82 := ODD(_t73, _t75);
_t83 := ODD(_t77, _t79);
_t84 := ODD(_t80, _t81);
_t85 := ODD(_t82, _t83);
_t86 := ODD(_t84, _t85);
_aBits := OR(A0, A1, A2);
_bBits := OR(B0, B1, B2, B3, B4);
ASSIGN _aBits, _bBits;
ASSIGN ~_t1, ~_t16, ~_t22, ~_t32, ~_t46, ~_t62, ~_t78, ~_t86;
```

In my experiments, the maximum number of bits in the number to be factored is rather low. Therefore, SAT solvers don't appear to be the silver bullet to defeat [RSA cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography).

**Example:** To factor the square of the seventh Mersenne prime (2^19-1)^2, an 38-bit number, the SAT solver `Z3` needed 186s.

A related paper is [Satisfy This: An Attempt at Solving Prime Factorization using Satisﬁability Solvers](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse573/04au/Project/mini1/TheS&Ateam/SATeamFinalPaper.pdf).